# What is causing SWIG to generate invalid code?

Tags: python, c, compiler-errors, windows-subsystem-for-linux, swig

I have been interfacing between Python and C using ctypes, and I have been trying to switch to using SWIG. However, the code generated by SWIG has errors and will not compile.

I have two .c files UTTT.c and UTTT_Library.c, a header file for both of the files, boardCount.h, and the interface file UTTT.i. I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux

After running `swig -python UTTT.i` and `gcc -c -fpic UTTT_wrap.c UTTT.c UTTT_Library.c -I/usr/local/include/python3.12` I get a compilation error in the code generated by SWIG:

```
UTTT_wrap.c: In function ‘_wrap_CGameState_board_set’:
UTTT_wrap.c:3555:60: error: assignment to expression with array type
           for (; jj < (size_t)3; ++jj) arg1->board[ii][jj] = arg2[ii][jj];
```

I am unsure exactly what the issue with the array assignment is, but I am also confused why SWIG is not generating valid code.

Here is the contents of UTTT.i

```
%module UTTT

%{
    #include "boardCount.h"
%}

%include boardCount.h
```

This is what setup.py contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from distutils.core import setup, Extension

example_module = Extension('_UTTT',sources = ['UTTT_wrap.cxx', 'UTTT_Library.c', "UTTT.c"])

setup (name = 'UTTT',
       version = '0.1',
       author      = "Robert Stegmann",
       description = """Library for ultimate tic tac toe""",
       ext_modules = [example_module],
       py_modules = ["UTTT"],
       )
```

Here is an excerpt from boardCount.h defining CGameState

```
#define ROW_DIMENSION 3
#define COL_DIMENSION ROW_DIMENSION

typedef struct {
    char board[9][ROW_DIMENSION][COL_DIMENSION];
    char boardsWon[ROW_DIMENSION][COL_DIMENSION];
    unsigned char currentBoard;
    unsigned char currentTurn;
    char gameWon;
} CGameState;
```

Here is the code generated by SWIG that has the issue

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_CGameState_board_set(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
  PyObject *resultobj = 0;
  CGameState *arg1 = (CGameState *) 0 ;
  char (*arg2)[3][3] ;
  void *argp1 = 0 ;
  int res1 = 0 ;
  void *argp2 = 0 ;
  int res2 = 0 ;
  PyObject * obj0 = 0 ;
  PyObject * obj1 = 0 ;
  
  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,(char *)"OO:CGameState_board_set",&obj0,&obj1)) SWIG_fail;
  res1 = SWIG_ConvertPtr(obj0, &argp1,SWIGTYPE_p_CGameState, 0 |  0 );
  if (!SWIG_IsOK(res1)) {
    SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res1), "in method '" "CGameState_board_set" "', argument " "1"" of type '" "CGameState *""'"); 
  }
  arg1 = (CGameState *)(argp1);
  res2 = SWIG_ConvertPtr(obj1, &argp2,SWIGTYPE_p_a_3__a_3__char, 0 |  0 );
  if (!SWIG_IsOK(res2)) {
    SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res2), "in method '" "CGameState_board_set" "', argument " "2"" of type '" "char [9][3][3]""'"); 
  } 
  arg2 = (char (*)[3][3])(argp2);
  {
    if (arg2) {
      size_t ii = 0;
      for (; ii < (size_t)9; ++ii) {
        if (arg2[ii]) {
          size_t jj = 0;
          for (; jj < (size_t)3; ++jj) arg1->board[ii][jj] = arg2[ii][jj];
        } else {
          SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ValueError, "invalid null reference " "in variable '""board""' of type '""char [9][3][3]""'");
        }
      }
    } else {
      SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ValueError, "invalid null reference " "in variable '""board""' of type '""char [9][3][3]""'");
    }
  }
  resultobj = SWIG_Py_Void();
  return resultobj;
fail:
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: The issue with array assignment is that you cannot assign to a (whole) array, and the compiler thinks that's what the generated wrapper is trying to do.  There might be a flaw in SWIG here, but if there is, it certainly revolves around the contents of your header, which you have not shown us.  Please provide the needed extra details and reduce the unnecessary ones to ensure that the question presents a [mre].

Comment: Post the definition of the `CGameState` structure, there might be something unusual in it.

Comment: I've updated the post with the definition of CGameState

Comment: FWIW, [Python's direct C API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html)  is IMO waaaay easier to understand than SWIG.  And it doesn't generate code that relies on undefined behavior to work like SWIG does...